# Solving a matrix $4\times 4$ over $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new to solving equation over $\mathbb{Z}_n$ so I would like to make sure I understand fully the material.

I'm trying to solve the following equations over $\mathbb{Z}_7$:
$$
\begin{cases}
3x+2y-z=-15\\
5x+3y+2z=0\\
3x+y+3z=11\\
x+y-4z=-30
\end{cases}$$

What I did:

$$\begin{pmatrix}3 & 2 & -1 & -15\\
5 & 3 & 2 & 0\\
3 & 1 & 3 & 11\\
1 & 1 & -4 & -30
\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & -4 & -30\\
5 & 3 & 2 & 0\\
3 & 1 & 3 & 11\\
3 & 2 & -1 & -15
\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & -4 & -30\\
0 & 5 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 5 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 6 & 4 & 5
\end{pmatrix}\to\begin{pmatrix}5 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 5 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

So we get:

$$\begin{cases}
5x=1\\
5y+z=3
\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
x=3\\
z=2y+3
\end{cases}$$

Meaning the answer is: $S=\{(x,y,z)\,:\,x,y,z\in\mathbb{Z}_{7}\}=\{(3,y,2y+3)\,:\,y\in\mathbb{Z}_{7}\}$.

Is it Correct? Also, how can I write $S$ with Span?

Comment: Why don't you represent all elements of $\Bbb{F}_7$ by elements of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$?

Comment: @Servaes But, it is correct?

Comment: It is very hard to figure out what you are doing, but the end result is certainly wrong because $3\times 3+2\times y-(2y+3)\neq-15$. What is your last step in the Gaussian elimination? How does the bottom row vanish?